# OpenVPN connection timeout

Tags: wireless, network-manager, openvpn

i am trying to establish a VPN connection using OpenVPN. I think have set up the VPN server correctly. I followed [this instructions](http://raspberrypi-hacks.com/29/turn-your-raspberry-into-an-openvpn-vpn-server/).

From the server i have received the files `ca.crt`, `ca.key`, `client1.crt`, `client1.csr`, `client1.key` and `raspberripi.ovpn`

What have i done so far?
I have installed `openvpn` and `network-manager-openvpn`. Wnt to the Network icon at the to right corner > VPN > Configure VPN > Create > Import from existing configurations

There i picked the `raspberrypi.ovpn`-file. All settings seemed correct so i saved the connection. But it fails to connect. It gives me the message "Connection could not be established because the network-connection caused a timeout"

I am sorry if the labels are not exactly as on your version of Ubuntu. Mine is in German and I translated them :P

here is the content from the `raspberrypi.ovpn` file:

```
dev tun
client
proto udp
remote le-morri.selfhost.bz 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
cert client1.crt
key client1.key
comp-lzo
verb 3
```

My Ubuntu version is: 13.04

I hope you can help me establish the connection.